# Calculate Correlation b/w all the numeric columns of a Spark Dataframe in R

Tags: r, correlation, sparkr

I have a Spark `Dataframe` with the below structure present in `R` :-

```
Var1----- Var 2----- Var 3 ------- Var 4----- Group  
98.64---- 32.35---- 11906.91-- 08.65----- A  
94.83---- 29.36---- 17287.57-- 06.01----- B  
99.94---- 35.36---- 30411.85-- 08.82----- C  
99.45---- 34.58---- 18267.26-- 10.09----- C  
99.93---- 36.64---- 23560.04-- 07.34----- A  
99.66---- 48.81---- 42076.44-- 08.44----- B  
99.96---- 27.38---- 18474.01-- 11.39----- A  
97.49---- 25.28---- 14615.50-- 06.60----- B  
98.98---- 32.50---- 10282.90-- 07.71----- C  
99.57---- 31.54---- 12725.56-- 06.17----- C  
99.91---- 26.46---- 10990.13-- 06.17----- C
```

This is my representative dataset, number of records are pretty huge. Similarly number of columns are more than 200 as well.

I need to calculate Correlation between all the numeric variables present in this `Spark` `Dataframe`.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this question as well. All I have found out is that SparkR supports "corr" directly on Spark data frames, but I find that it takes only 2 column values as arguments. It would however be easier if there was a way to compute correlation of "all" the columns in the data frame at once.